# JavaScript Reflection: obtaining a variable's name?

Tags: javascript, variables, get, scope

I have a several variables which are assigned to the same **function**. The property 'name' is "" as this function is anonymous;

There also isn't a function call involved, and as such no callee.

Is there a way in JS to obtain the variable's name, through a self-implemented reflection algorithm?

**e.g.**

```
var x = function(){}
var myUnknownNamedVar1 = myUnknownNamedVar2 = x;
```

**Background**:

for space efficiency, thousands of variable names are assigned to the same 'static' function as a lazy-loaded stumps, which get resolved to individual functions upon the first call invocation. (The variable name also contains a namespace).

**Alternatives**:

My alternative would be the use of objects such as `{_name: myUnknownNamedVar1 , _fn: x}`

Solutions to this issue would be interesting. A particular issue is discerning variables with different names ,in the script, which point to the same object.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You want to find the string names of variables that point to `x`?

Comment: fnmap.remoteNotYetMappedFunc(1,2,3,4) 1. store the parameters in a queue 2. load remote information and create an individual function and reassign it to fnmap.remoteNotYetMappedFunc

Comment: If your question is can you get the names of variables pointing to an object the answer is no. If your scenario is different (e.g. you could iterate through a namespace and check references), then it might be possible, but I didn't understand any of your explanation.

Comment: Let me know if I understand your question correctly.  I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. You could try parsing the script's text.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/gXWnx/)

```
var x = function(){}
var myUnknownNamedVar1 = myUnknownNamedVar2 = x;

var txt  = (document.currentScript && document.currentScript.textContent) ||
           (document.scripts       && document.scripts[1]
                                   && document.scripts[1].textContent);
var arr  = txt.match(/var\s*(.*)\s*=\s*x\b/);
arr[1]   = arr[1].replace(/\s+$/,"");
var vars = arr[1].split(/\s*=\s*/);

// vars: ["myUnknownNamedVar1", "myUnknownNamedVar2"]
```

---

#### 2. You can try comparing values

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/wYnD7/1/)

```
var x = function(){}
var myUnknownNamedVar1 = myUnknownNamedVar2 = x;

var vars = [];
for (var prop in window){
    if (window[prop] == x)
      vars.push(prop);
}

// vars: ["x", "myUnknownNamedVar1", "myUnknownNamedVar2"]
```

---

***Note:** Both methods will need refining (eg recursion, better/more match patterns). The second one only looks at global variables, whereas some variables in closures may not be exposed to the global namespace.  Also, there are objects of objects.*

Comment: A creative solution, albeit not very robust. Firstly it only matches `var`ed and defined variables. So if I did `var a;` and later on did the assignment it wouldn't pick it up. Nor would it pick up other methods of assignment, like return values, or a simple `a=x;b=a;` etc. Also it's a little too greedy, it matches much more than it should because of the `.*` It's also easily fooled by string literals. Regular expressions are definitely not powerful enough to parse the language, let alone analyse it.

Comment: A 'Reflection' solution. Good job! (PS: currentScript is Non-standard / Gecko-Engine). Can you make this cross-browser compatible, and I'll take your answer.)

Comment: @davin: you are right on all accounts.  As I stated, there would need some recursion as well as more pattern matches.  But given the OP's example, it works.  I can't magically know his syntax (especially if he used frameworks) without him telling/showing.  In the answer above `.*` is purposefully greedy in order to split later for `a= b = c =d=x` cases.

Comment: @Lo-lsauer.com I thought I did modify by using `document.scripts` in addition to `document.currentScript`.  Note, the code isn't necessarily in `scripts[1]`, so you might want to also loop through the scripts array.

Comment: Do you know how to access the 'running scripts' in a cross-browser manner, rather than the content of the DOM script-tags?

Comment: @Lo-lsauer.com I don't know of any way and I would think that would be difficult, since you would be accessing the memory/processes of the browser itself, which is a security concern.  When the scripts are loaded they are parsed and and added to the DOM accordingly, which the `window.document.scripts` array contains.  Though, you could also get to them by traversing `document.head`, or `document.body` based on where the script was defined.

Answer (score 10):

It is possible to use object reflection, as such:

```
const getVarName = obj => Object.keys(obj)[0];
const varToGetTheNameOf = "Value!";
getVarName({ varToGetTheNameOf }) // => "varToGetTheNameOf"
```

Answer (score 3):

No. There is not.

A simple explanation (that reinforces the point in the post) for this is simply: a variable (or property) is *not* a value/object. Rather, it is a "name" for a value/object. The same object can be named multiple times.

Imagine this example, and consider how it maps to "names" given to people :-)

```
var fred = function Fred () {}
fred.name // "Fred"

// An unknown number of nicknames can exist...
var francisco = fred
var frankyTheFiveFingers = fred
someOtherRegion.theGoodPerson = fred

// But sometimes nicknames are known; note that this is
// a locatable (e.g. "known") iterable set.
// (While properties can be iterated, variables cannot.
//  However, iterating *every* object is not feasible, hence
//  it must be a locatable set.)
fred.nicknames = ["Freddy", "FD"]

mary.nicknamesFor(fred) // who knows :-)
```

Happy coding.

Comment: well feasible yes, e.g. via code-shaping / 'Reflection'. Some straightforward trickery would be nice. I will go for individual call-delegation closures, and bear the slight loading-time and memory-overhead. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can use decorators to detect the name of variable that must be :

(a)- Class

(b)- Attribute of class or of instance

(c)- Method of class or of instance

---

The decorator provides 3 informations about the decorated :

1. target
2. key
3. Descriptor

Thus:

- the name of (a) is `target.name`
- the name of (b) or (c) is `key` directly

  ```
   function logName(target, key) {
     console.log(!key ? target.name : key);
   }
  ```

**example ([Try Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/s6wkgwvx/1/))**  :

```
  @logName
  class Person {

     @logName
     firstname="Someone";

     @logName
     fullName() {
       return this.firstname+' '+this.lastname;
     }

  }
```

[Try Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/s6wkgwvx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

One trick you can do is something like this:

```js
    
let myVariable = 1;
console.log((()=>myVariable).toString().replace('()=>', ''))
```